# IIS 10 and Custom Error Pages-Executing Twice

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-10

In response to the infamous "xmlrpc.php" DOS attacks, I wrote custom error ASP pages for both the 404 and the 500-100 type of errors and got most of it working okay.  However, I found that the pages are being executed twice, for unknown reason. They both send emails, and also collect the client's IP, for automatic adding to a Peerblock custom IP block list text file.  However, because of the double-execution, two (2) emails are sent, and the IP addresses are added twice to the Peerblock text file.  Following is a code snippet listing for the 404 page:

```
' Grab the current URL and peform a number of tests (if we can--after the IIS server performs a redirection to a 404 handler, the URL is stripped of all parameters):
TheURL = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
If Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") <> "" Then
    TheURL = TheURL & "?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
End If

strServer = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
strUrl = Request.QueryString
strPage = Mid(strUrl, InStr(strUrl, strServer) + Len(strServer) + 1)
ClientIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")  
HTTPReferer = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

If HTTPReferer = "" Then
    If InStr(1, ClientIPAddress, "10.1.252.250", 0) > 0 Then 
        HTTPReferer = "www.edenusa.com"
        WithinSite = True
    Else
        HTTPReferer = "UNKNOWN URL" 
        WithinSite = False
    End If
End If

' Grab the IP address of the client coming into site (used later in email and HTML text):
RemoteIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

' Don't notify via email when the URL is the following (happens too often):
HTTPRefererStatus = InStr(HTTPReferer, "edenusa.com/") OR InStr(HTTPReferer, "www.edenusa.com/") OR InStr(HTTPReferer, "edenusa.com/favicon.ico") OR InStr(HTTPReferer, "edenusa.com/favicon.gif") OR InStr(HTTPReferer, "edenusa.com/robots.txt") OR InStr(HTTPReferer, "xmlrpc.php")
TheURLStatus = InStr(TheURL, "xmlrpc.php")

If HTTPRefererStatus > 0 Or TheURLStatus > 0 Then

    NoEmail = True ' Do not send an email in this case

    If TheURLStatus > 0 Then ' Write the IP address to our own local Peer Block list:
        ' The format of the file is as follows: #[name]:[IpRangeStart]-[IpRangeEnd]

        Dim objFS
        Dim objFile
        Dim IPBlockFileName: IPBlockFileName = "badiplist-edenusa.txt"

        Set objFS = Server.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sIPBlockListPath = Server.Mappath ("/common/errorhandling/badiplists/" & IPBlockFileName)
        Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile (sIPBlockListPath, 8)

        ' Write the IP address out to the IP Block List file:
        objFile.WriteLine "#Test: " & RemoteIPAddress & "-" & RemoteIPAddress

        objFile.Close
        Set objFS = Nothing
        Set objFile = Nothing
    End If
End If


' Using Persits ASPEmail component, send an error report email to the support team.

sAlertBody = "At " & Now() & " a 404 error was encountered when a user attempted to visit the following link: " & HTTPReferer & vbCrLf
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & "The local IP address is: " & ClientIPAddress
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & "The remote IP address is: " & RemoteIPAddress
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & "The value of TheURL is: " & TheURL
sAlertBody = sAlertBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

'Send email for evaluation:
'Function IsSuccessfulEmail(sFromAddress, sSenderName, sRecipient, sReplyTo, sSubject, sBody, sCarbonCopyAddress, sFileAttachmentLocation)

If NoEmail = False Then

' Call the emailing function (contained in the /INCLUDEFILES/EMAILOPERATIONS/EMAILFUNCTIONS.ASP file):

    ' Call the AdministrativeAlertEmail() function:
    AlertEmailResult = AdministrativeAlertEmail(sAlertRecipient, sAlertSubject, sAlertBody, sAlertHost)

        If Debug_404ErrorPage = True Then
            Response.Write("LINE-178: This is the value of the AlertEmailResult variable: ") & AlertEmailResult & "<br>"
            Response.End
        End If

Else ' Do not send an email, and reset the variable back to TRUE:

    NoEmail = True

End If
```

Comment: Just wondering about the logic of the `if NoEmail`-statement. It checks if it's false, and then else set it to true. But that that point it would already be true since it failed the statement. So what is it you're going for there?

Comment: Hello Daniel.  Thank you for your comment.  I wondered about that myself.  I believe the original programmer was trying to prevent the double email from happening.  The part that I added is the creation of the IP Block List file for Peerblock to use.  As you can see in the code, that was done to block the numerous attempts by hackers to hit what they think is a Wordpress site with an XMLRPC DOC attack.  However, the logic of the "NoEmail" code aside, the page executes TWICE every time a 404 error occurs on the site.  That's the original posted problem, and occurs with any of the custom pages.

Comment: I have been searching on Google for both a resolution to this problem, and am trying to figure out how I can contact Microsoft about this, but cannot find any information on either topic.

Comment: you could try to use the fiddler tool to check if the request got sent twice. another thing is to try to attach the worker process in visual studio and debug your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484235/how-to-open-classic-asp-website-locally-and-attach-to-it-in-visual-studio

Comment: A quick and messy hack could be to try and add a timestamp in a session at the end of the function, and then do a check before the function that if that session timestamp is less than a second, don't execute the code. That way it should prevent double executions.

Comment: Is it the error is being sent twice or is the custom error page causing the error? The emails that you receive, are they both 404 errors? Try removing the 500-100 custom error to see if it still happens.

Comment: @Lankymart-Indeed, the custom error page mechanism is the culprit.  I removed the 500-100 custom page as you suggested, and now the custom 404 page only executes one time.  Therefore, the issue is now one of how to properly fix the Server.GetLastError() issue, which appears to be the real problem (I followed the advice of an article I found online of a "fix" to this issue).  I will post this as a new question.  Thank you all for your excellent help.

Answer (score 1):

The IIS Custom Error pages tool allows the definition of a custom error page via the "Error Page" mechanism.  Each Status Code type (e.g., 500), can be edited to include a relative path to your own custom error page.  Unfortunately, I discovered that Server.GetLastError() method that I instantiated in the 500 page, returns only null values.  An article on the net described a solution whereby the "Edit Feature Settings..." in IIS could be used to point to a "Default Page."  This unfortunately, caused all other defined Custom Error Pages to be executed twice.  Upon removing the custom 500 error page (as suggested by Lankymart), the problem described in this post was resolved.