# Visual Studio Interdev 6.0 Installation

Tags: visual-studio

I have been tasked with putting together a development server and client (Windows 10), using Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 with Visual Interdev, so that a team of developers can debug a very large ASP Classic website.  I have studied up and found that Visual Studio 6.0 can be installed on Windows 10, so that takes care of the client side, but I am wondering what version of Windows Server I should use for the development server?  I have access to 2003, 2012 R2, 2016, and 2019 versions.  The original OS used back in the day appears to have been Windows Server NT.

Comment: VS 6.0 is before year 2000, so the closest would be 2003. However I don't understand the rationale... why can't you use more modern VS? Even for classic ASP.

Comment: The Visual Interdev IDE is familiar to the developers, and allows for debugging ASP Classic code.  I personally do not know how to enable debugging of ASP Classic in any of the modern Visual Studio IDEs.  If there is a way to do this, I am all ears and perhaps could consult with them on going this route, especially since the production site is running on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: @paulscott https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765105/1682881

Comment: I will try that link over this coming weekend, and then will report back.  Thank you very much!